# Clone only specific path - Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Is there any way by chance to make spring config server to clone only specific path instead of whole git repo? When I'm running it on production I may not want my entire code base repository to be cloned to some location as it is always a risk. I've done my research and couldn't figure out ways to clone only specific paths of git repo.

One solution is to host the configurations in a seperate repo. But that would defeat the purpose of **one code many deploys** suggestion of 12factor.net.

Another possibility is to copy the properties into config server's classpath and then to use native profile to load them. But this would defeat the purpose of Spring ConfigServer.

Also kindly do clarify What would be the best way to run spring config server on a production?

Comment: You should use a separate repo for configuration

Comment: But as per 12 factor in microservices if we use seperate codebase for config then it voids one code base multiple deploys right?

Comment: we see this as externalized configuration, slightly different than 12factor.net config in env.

Comment: But this externalized config is for microservices so I'm trying to follow 12factor.net config recommendations.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say

Comment: I hope I'm not confusing things here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be separating your code base from your configuration settings.

Repo 1: Your App Code

Repo 2: Your Spring Cloud Config Server Code

Repo 3: Your configuration settings

When you're **deploying**, you're deploying the **code**. Not the configuration. A configuration change should not require a new **deployment**. A new deployment **might** require an updated configuration change, but the two are generally decoupled.

Configuration can be dynamically updated while code is running. This is completely separate from updating code and deploying the app. That's the whole point of externalized configuration.

TL;DR: You're looking at "one code many deploys" wrong. Configuration is externalized.

Answer (score 1):

I took this straight from 12factor.net

Apps sometimes store config as constants in the code. This is a violation of twelve-factor, which requires strict separation of config from code. Config varies substantially across deploys, code does not.

Even though you are no longer storing them as constants but still in the same repository is not enough separation from the code. Use a separate repository for configurations.

Comment: But creating a seperate repo to store config is again violating one code many deploys. Please checkout question comments for the discussion of the same.

Comment: I'm not finding one code many deploys on the 12factor.net page. I guess it depends on your definition of deployment. Updating a git repository usually isn't treated as a deploy.

Comment: that's what even I'm confused about.